# Are there programs to create and edit SVG animations?

Tags: animation, svg

Looks like there is a standard open format for vector animation: SVG.

How to create and edit such files?

I expect something like Blender with keyframes and curve editor. Inkscape does not seem to have animation abilities at the first glance.

FOSS is strongly preferred (so Flash-related things are discouraged, but if there is a Flash to animated SVG converter it should be mentioned).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here there is a list of already existing animation programs (including SVG animation) http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Animation-%28Timeline%29

There are both FOSS and proprietary ones.

Answer (score 0):

Since inkscape list does not include a brand new product I will list it in addition to the accepted answer:

Non free

https://aphalina.com/ - commercial SVG Animation Studio similar to Macromedia Dreamviewer and Microsoft Expression Blend.

Disclaimer: This product is created by my friend. I do not work for him.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the online service for creating SVG animations https://alterdraft.com/svg-animator  I use it very often, there is no need to install anything. + The project is constantly adding new features.